# Why can't I increment a global variable within a list comprehension expression?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I would like to write this list comprehension:

```py
[k += 1 for g in new if g % 2 == 0]
```

to obtain the same result as does the `for` loop in the code below, but it throws an error (`invalid syntax`, with the incrementation operator highlighted in red). Why is it not allowing me to increment the `k` variable inside the list comprehension?

The following code works, but I want to replace the `for` loop with a single-line expression, like the one above.

```py
R = bin(39)[2:]
k = 0
new = []
lst1 = [i for i, char in enumerate(R) if char == '1']
[new.append(j + 1) for j in lst1]
for g in new:
    if g % 2 == 0:
        k += 1
print(k)
```

Comment: you can create list with `1` and later `sum()` this list `k = sum([ 1 for g in new if g % 2 == 0])`

Comment: instead of `[new.append(j + 1) for j in lst1]` you should do `new = [j + 1 for j in lst1]`

Comment: instead of creating `lst1` and later  `new` you could do all in one `list comprehension` using `j+1` when you create `lst1`, or using `enumerate(R, 1)`. Frankly you could even directly run `j%2 == 0` to create list of `True, False` and `sum()` will treat it as `1, 0`

Comment: a list comprehensions isn't a "one line loop". It is a construct for expressing **mapping flitering operationts** on an arbitrary iterables to **create a list**. You shouldn't use them for side-effects, e.g. `new.append`

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are for creating new list with new values, not to increase external value (`k`).

Instead of `k += 1` you can use `1` to create list with `1` and later  use `sum()` to calculate `k`

```
k = sum([1 for g in new if g % 2 == 0])
```

---

BTW:

Instead of using `new.apeend()` you should directly put values

```
new = [j + 1 for j in lst1]
```

But you could do it directly when you create `lst1`

- use `i+1` instead of i`

  ```
  new = [i+1 for i, char in enumerate(R) if char == '1']
  ```
- or use `enumerate(R, 1)`

  ```
  new = [i for i, char in enumerate(R, 1) if char == '1']
  ```

You could even directly check `% 2`

```
new = [i%2==0 for i, char in enumerate(R, 1) if char == '1']
```

and this will create list with `True` and `False` - and `sum()` treads `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`

```
k = sum([i%2==0 for i, char in enumerate(R, 1) if char == '1'])
```

Or you can use longer `if`

```
k = sum([1 for i, char in enumerate(R, 1) if (char == '1') and (i % 2 == 0)])
```

In this version you calculate sum for list with only values `1` - so you can get the same result using `len()` instead of `sum()`

```
k = len([1 for i, char in enumerate(R, 1) if (char == '1') and (i % 2 == 0)])
```